# How to draw connecting lines between two uitableviewcells ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, drawing, core-graphics

I want to show links between two cells of uiTableView.

For Ex:
To show links between cells 1 and 5, it could be shown like:[image]

Does any one has any idea how this can be achieved. Also when table scrolls, these links should be scrolled with it.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/tag/core-graphics

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you want to build hierarchical view. Your implementation might be rejected by Apple due to not taking HIG into account.

Also what will be in case when lower part is not seen to user? Arrow with no end and need to scroll down for the user?

You might want to do a tree like structure (anything hierarchical) instead of ugly (sorry for that) arrows.

Comment: It's not the hierarchical views. They are separate cells. I just want to show, they are connected in some manner.
The app is not going on app store, so I m not worried about HIG much.
Will have to work on UI, it's just the rough version
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want arrow between two cell then make a separate `UIView` class for the Tablecell, in that `UIView` add one `UILabel` for text and one `UIImageView` for arrow, adjust there position as per your requirement.

Now pass this `UIView` to cell.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I think this solution will work only if cells are same section.

Answer (score 0):

`UITableViewCell` is just a subclass of `UIView` and `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`.  The only fanciness that UITableView provides is creating/reusing the cells and laying them out in the scroll view.  (That's a gross over-simplification but for this It'll do the trick.)

So if I have a `UIView` subclass that draws an arrow, then it's just a matter of getting the frame for the cells I want to point to.  `CGRect frame1 = [[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] frame];`

Some pseudocode...

```
topCellFrame = get top cell frame;
bottomCellFrame = get bottom cell frame;
arrow = new arrow view;
arrow set frame = frame with origin of top cell frame origin, and height of distance from topCellFrame to bottomCellFrame;
tableView add subview = arrow;
```

There are edge cases to think about, If the top cell or bottom cell are offscreen the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` will return nil and frame will be `CGRectZero`.

But I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

Edit:  (I haven't done this exact thing, but I have done some similar things with the frames of cells)